# Excel / Calc Formula to pull product cost from a list of SKUs

Tags: excel, openoffice-calc

I have a workbook with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 contains 2 columns, first column is a list of SKU numbers. Second column is a list of the SKU cost, like below:

```
SKU    Cost
B5     $3.00
G7     $7.50
```

The second sheet in the workbook is sales data. What I'm trying to do is add a Cost column to this second sheet and run a formula that looks up the SKU in each Row of Data in Sheet 2 and then puts the corresponding cost data from Sheet 1 into the Cost Column and row in Sheet 2. Here is an example:

Sheet 2:

```
SKU    Sold Price   Cost
G7      $14.99       $7.50 (Obtained by looking up the SKU in Sheet 1)
B5      $12.99       $3.00 (Obtained by looking up the SKU in Sheet 1)
```

I tried using the MATCH function but ended up getting error 503s or 504s, so something isn't right. Does anyone know the best formula to do something like this? I read that VLOOKUP is not ideal since it will be slow and the SKUs or Costs would have to be in alphabetical or numerical order. Thank you.

[Sheet1 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBpwu.png)

[Sheet2 Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7enV6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=INDEX(Table1[Cost],MATCH([@SKU],Table1[SKU],0))`

Comment: This is assuming your data is in tables. if not use `=INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A,0))`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. My data is not in tables, so I used your second formula and I'm getting a #Name? error when pasting the formula into the Cost column on Sheet 2.

Comment: What did you name the sheets (the tabs at the bottom)?

Comment: Sheet1 and Sheet 2

Comment: Is the data in the first sheet in column A and column B?

Comment: Also. I would recommend you turn them into tables. It makes it a LOT easier to work with. just select any of the cells in the table and type `ctrl+L` and hit `Enter`.

Comment: You are using LibreOffice, not excel. I don't know what the formulas are for that program, but try this, `=INDEX(Sheet1.B:B; MATCH(A2; Sheet1.A:A; 0))`.

Comment: Couldn't get it to work in LibreOffice so I switched computers and tried it in Excel and it is not giving me an error anymore but it is giving me the same cost ($7.50) for both SKUs for some reason.

Comment: You need to make sure the `A2` is referencing the correct cell

Comment: That worked. I used =INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,MATCH(A2, Sheet1!A:A,0)) 
Then copy and pasted that formula in the next row and changed A2 to A3, after that I can highlight the first cells with the formula, click on the Bottom right corner and drag it all the way down to automatically update and run the formula for each cell, A4, A5, A6... etc.) Thank you, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Glad I could help. Could you check the check mark for this answer to indicate the question has been resolved?